# Python code object, function, and default parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

### Investigation

I have this program

```
def gen_baz():
    return 2

def gen_bar(a, b, c=1):
    return a, b, c

# ---------- #

# Save the code objects
c1 = gen_bar.__code__
c2 = gen_baz.__code__

dis.dis(gen_bar) # [Disassambly 1]
print(inspect.getsource(gen_bar)) # [Inspect 1]

bar = gen_bar(1, 2) # bar: (1, 2, 1)
baz = gen_baz() # baz: 2
print(f"before: bar={bar}, baz={baz}")

# --------- #

gen_bar.__code__, gen_baz.__code__ = c2, c1 # swap code objects between 2 functions

dis.dis(gen_baz) # [Disassambly 2]
print(inspect.getsource(gen_baz))  # [Inspect 1]

bar = gen_bar() # bar: 2
baz = gen_baz(1, 2) # baz: [Error 1]
print(f"after: bar={bar}, baz={baz}")
```

Here are the outputs with Disassembly and Inspect

```
[Disassembly 1 & 2]
 17           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              3
              8 RETURN_VALUE

[Inspect 1 & 2]
def gen_bar(a, b, c=1):
    return a, b, c

[Error 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\something\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    baz = gen_baz(1, 2)
TypeError: gen_baz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

### Question

1. Why after I swapped the code objects between baz and bar, the program crashed? Even though they have identical byte code **and** inspect result
2. Where is the default parameter in python stored? Does it come along with the function object but not the code object? If so, then how does Inspect module gives me `c=1` on the second inspection?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The default values, at least, are indeed stored in the function itself (`gen_bar.__defaults__`). `getsource`, as implied by the name, is looking at the *source code* that generated the object, not the object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default values are not stored in the `code` object. They are stored directly in the `function` object.

```
>>> gen_bar.__defaults__
(1,)
```

The text returned by `getsource` comes, as implied by the name, from the source code itself, not the object generated *by* the source code. (At the object level, the signature is only implied by the values the function tries to load from the stack, global namespace, etc.)

You can use `inspect.signature` to see that `gen_baz` now takes three arguments, but that does *not* include the default value, which was not transferred to `gen_baz` along with the `code` object.

```
>>> inspect.signature(gen_baz)
<Signature (a, b, c)>
```

---

The *use* of a default argument value is buried in the evaluation of the `CALL_FUNCTION` opcode. Given

```
def foo(a=1):
    return a
```

You can see that neither its byte code

```
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

nor calls with or without explicit arguments

```
>>> dis.dis('foo(9)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (9)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('foo()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

make use of the function's `__defaults__` attribute. In the function, it is simply *assumed* that some value can pushed on to the stack from the local variable `a`, regardless of how that variable is set. In both calls, a value is simply loaded onto the stack or not before using `CALL_FUNCTION`.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#module-inspect):

- `__code__`: code object containing compiled function bytecode
- `__defaults__`: tuple of any default values for positional or keyword parameters
- `__kwdefaults__`: mapping of any default values for keyword-only parameters